# Fragment is not destroyed but onCreateView is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, runtime-permissions

I have an `Activity`and it has `ViewPager`. This`ViewPager` loads `Fragments` using `Adapter`. My each fragment is considered as **Section** (as per app functionality). Initially I load all the `ViewPager` items once using,

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(sectionList.size()); //sectionList is nothing but number of framgents`

In fragment I have a function called `setup` called from `Adapter` class while creating the fragment.

**InvestigationFragment**

```
public void setup(SectionView sectionView, int pos) {
    this.sectionView = sectionView;
    this.pos = pos;
}
```

**InvestigationAdapter**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    InvestigationFragment investigationFragment = new InvestigationFragment();
    investigationFragment.setup(sectionViewHashMap.get(keys.get(pos)), pos);
    fragments.add(investigationFragment);
    return investigationFragment;
}
```

**Here the `SectionView` is a abstract class extended by class `SimpleSection`. And `SimpleSection` adds the custom views inside it. The custom views are like around 20-30 view classes.**

```
public abstract class SectionView {

    public Section mSection;
    public Context mContext;
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, SectionView> subSectionViews;
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, FieldWidget> fieldWidget;
    public int actionSaveId;
    protected LinearLayout sectionView;
    protected Toolbar toolbar;

    public final void initialiseSection(Toolbar toolbar) {
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
        createFields();
        createSubSection();
    }

    public final void buildSection(LinearLayout v) {
        sectionView = v;
        addFields();
        addSubSection();
    }

    protected abstract void createFields();
    protected abstract void createSubSection();
    protected abstract void addFields();
    protected abstract void addSubSection();
    public abstract boolean hasSubSection();
    public abstract boolean validateSection();
    protected abstract boolean persistSection();

    public final boolean saveSection() {
        boolean isSaved = true;
            if (!validateSection()) {
                isSaved = false;
            } else if (!persistSection()) {
                isSaved = false;
            }
        return isSaved;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine till here. But the SectionView is going null in some scenarios where I'm not able to retain it. Here are the scenario,

1. I have custom camera implementation, from fragment I open my custom camera **(without destroying fragment or activity)**, capture image and I come back to fragment `onCreateView()` is called sometimes, so `sectionView` is going null. When I debugged, none of the lifecycle methods are called (such as `onDestroyView()`, `onDestroy()`, `onDetach()`, `onLowMemeory()`, `onConfigurationChanged()`). Then how `onCreateView()` can be called?
2. In Nexus 9, while changing run time permissions the same happened. I'll be in `Fragment`, Scroll down Status Bar > go to Settings > Apps > App Permissions > Location > Revoke Location Permission. If I grant the permission it won't crash, but if I revoke the sectionView object will be null

**WEIRD BEHAVIOR :** To check the 2nd scenario, I connected debugger to make sure fragment/activity is destroyed or not while revoking the `Location` permission. **As soon as I revoked the Location Permission, the debugger got disconnected and application is Killed/DEAD. This happens whenever I revoke any permissions.**

Now how can I make sure the `sectionView` object is retained or not destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

A few things. You can set your Offscreen page limit to size() -1 because one of them is always on screen.

Rather than having a setup method on your fragments I'd suggest instantiating your fragments with the values you want. So create a static method in InvestigationFragment called newInstance which takes the SectionView and position parameters.

E.g.

```
public static InvestigationFragment newInstance(SectionView sectionView, int pos) {
    final InvestigationFragment fragment = new InvestigationFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("SectionView", sectionView); //Depends on what type this as to what the put method is
    args.putInt("Position", position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

You should then read these values back in the onCreate of InvestigationFragment e.g.

```
sectionView = (SectionView) getArguments().getSerializable("SectionView");
```

This should allow your InvestigationFragment to survive rotation changes etc. correctly.

In your Adapter class I'd suggest just doing:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
      return InvestigationFragment.newInstance(sectionViewHashMap.get(keys.get(position)), position);
}
```

If you really need to maintain a list of fragments in your pager adapter you should override instantiateItem and destroyItem as follows:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final InvestigationFragment fragment = (InvestigationFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    fragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer let me work on this and let you know

Comment: Okie, I gave look at your answer. But I have a problem, as I mentioned `SectionView` is an **AbstractClass**. I extends this Abstract Class in many of my custom view classes. If I make `SectionView` class implements `Serializable` interface then I have to make all other classes which extends this should also implements 'Serializable` right? If I don't do, then it will throw me `NotSerializableException`! For example : `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`. In one of my custom view has `AppCompatEditText`. What should I do for this?

Comment: I just edited my question little brief on the abstract classes part. My abstract class is extended by another class where it add custom views in it. So I don't think this gonna help out. I think I have to re-structure. But any suggestions or solutions are welcomed please...

Comment: Is it possible just to have different primitive values that would allow you to specify the different layouts for the SectionView. Alternatively perhaps subclass InvestigationFragment with different layouts and ensure that the correct one is added from the getItem. If there are huge differences between each one you could also create an InvestigationFragment factory that returns the correct Fragment type for each position.

Comment: But the thing is, I cannot make the UI components abstract right?